According to Ockham’s Razor, how can we be sure a religion is verifiable?
Ockham’s Razor states that the answer with the fewest assumptions is correct, but what is the answer with the fewest assumptions? It could be anything, but we wouldn’t know until we already had the answer. Therefore, I think that the fact that we are living in a physical world in a universe with nothing controlling us would be the answer with the least assumptions. Using this logic, how can religion exist?

Religions exist: it is a fact, historical and empirically verifiable.

Maybe the question is: How can we be sure a religion could be right?

Interesting idea

That is not what Ockham’s Razor states, even Wikipedia is more subtle, "when presented with competing hypotheses about the same prediction and both theories have equal explanatory power one should prefer the hypothesis that requires the fewest assumptions." If it did state that the "answer with the fewest assumptions is correct" it would have been refuted many times over. Not to mention that nobody ever came up with a non-controversial way of counting "assumptions" or measuring "explanatory power".

No need of any Razor. Any religion is just a set of beliefs (in formal terms, it is just a non-empty set of belief objects), so it just exists even if there's no believers.

The razor you mention is one of the most misunderstood and misapplied ideas in philosophy, to judge by the many instances on PSE.
O's R definitely does not tell us that 'the answer with fewest assumptions is correct'. A helpful way to think about it is that every unproven assumption you make has some probability of being wrong, so by eliminating assumptions you are reducing the number of ways in which you can be wrong. That said, an answer with ten plausible assumptions can still be better than an answer with one ridiculous assumption- you have to take the probability of the assumption into account.

Ockham’s Razor cannot be used to exlude religion. Religion is not a theory, nor an intellectual hypotheses, but an experiential state of being with deep social-cultural roots.


Your statement of Occam’s razor leaves out one important
presupposition: If both theories have the same explanatory strength
then one should use the theory with uses fewer theoretical entities.

Mauro's comment and Paizis' answer emphasize that the existence
of religion is a fact and cannot be put into question.

But one can ask a normative question when comparing theistic and
atheistic explanations for a given phenomenon: Which of the two
should be preferred according to Occam’s razor?
Of course one cannot
just count the number of theoretical concepts of both explanations. One
has to consider also the clarity of these  concepts, the consistency of
the argumentation built on these concepts etc.


